# New Line After Each 72 Character

Tags: .net

Have some long base64 string, which must be formated with New Line every 72 byte and converted to byte array.

Have:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String("..."), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
```

But it inserts new line every 76 byte.
And how can i convert it back to byte array with preserved new lines?

Comment: It looks like `Convert.FromBase64String` ignores whitespace, so you lose your line breaks.  When you call `Convert.ToBase64String`, use `Base64FormattingOptions.None`, then use a loop and substrings to manually insert the line breaks.  Sorry, no magic bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set string into `StringBuilder` and use method `Insert()` in loop

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("the string");
for (int i = 72; i < sb.Length; i+=74)//72 + "\r\n"
{
    sb.Insert(i, "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Does C# re-evaluate the `for` condition on each iteration? I found that VB doesn't if you use a `for` loop but does if you use a `while` loop.

Comment: @MarkBerry both should re-evaluate because infinity loop

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else wants to do this in VB... I converted @burning_LEGION's splitting loop to VB.NET like this:

```
For i = 72 To sb.Length Step 74
    sb.Insert(i, vbCrLf)
Next
```

This has a problem:  the "end" statement (`sb.Length`) is only evaluated once, when the for loop starts. If the string is, for example, 656 characters long, VB will only split it onto eight lines even though, after adding the CRLFs, it should be nine lines.  This leaves the last line longer than the rest.  For a very large object, this could be quite significant.

Apparently the `Do While` statement behaves as desired, re-calculating the "while" condition on each iteration as the string gets longer:

```
i = 72
Do While i < sb.Length
    sb.Insert(i, vbCrLf)
    i += 74
Loop
```